# Менять z-позицию объектов в канвас (fabric.js)

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, fabricjs

На холсте находится несколько объектов, надо менять *z-позицию* объектов.

Можно это как-то сделать с *fabric.js*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть четыре метода для работы со слоями, как в PowerPoint:

`.sendBackwards()`, `.sendToBack()`, `.bringForward()`, `bringToFront()`

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 120, fill: 'green', left: 20, top: 0
});
var triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
  width: 120, height: 130, fill: 'blue', left: 0, top: 00
});

canvas.add(circle, triangle);

canvas.renderAll();

canvas.bringToFront(circle);
```

Демо: http://jsfiddle.net/gz2ae1p8/

Comment: Ваш вариант работает, спасибо) Но я для эксперимента попробовал менять местами объекты в массиве canvas и после перерисовывать, тоже работает.

`var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var a = canvas.getObjects();
var a = a[1];
a[1] = a[2];
a[2] = a;
canvas.renderAll();`